# pass the intent to the native addressbook when not useful for the application

Tags: android, native, edit, contacts

I had already asked this question but I deleted it by mistake. Sorry for sending it again.
I registered one of my activities to be started when the user chooses to edit a contact in the native address book.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="contacts"
                android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" />
            <data
                android:host="com.android.contacts"
                android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/contact" />
            <data
                android:host="com.android.contacts"
                android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/raw_contact" />                       
        </intent-filter>
```

Now the user is asked whether to use my application or the native one.

I would like to be able to pass the responsibility to the native application in case my application doesn't have anything to do with that contact.

How can I do it without having the user been asked again about the application to be used?

Thanks